# vimeo/youtube video embed with thumbnails

Tags: embed, youtube

Is there a way to get wordpress to embed Vimeo, YouTube videos like tumblr with a thumbnail and then to play without the player buttons?

examples -

- http://ascender.tumblr.com/
- http://swell-theme.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 5):

If you embed a vimeo video at that size it hides the playback buttons, no magic involved.

**EDIT-**

to display a static thumb of a youtube video:

your video url:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQO-aOdJLiw

take the `v=` portion of the url to get the large thumb url:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/WQO-aOdJLiw/0.jpg

and the small thumb url:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/WQO-aOdJLiw/1.jpg

Comment: ah,ok. Is there any way to hide the player elements on higher sizes?

Comment: @david arthur - not that I'm aware of. an option may be to just grab the static thumbnail and display that, then only load the video when the thumb is clicked. you'll still get playback controls though once the video starts. check the edited answer above.